# Click on Save button on File Download popup in IE11 in robot framework

Tags: robotframework, autoit

Is there a way to click on the Save or Open button in the pop up that appears while downloading a file in IE 11? I am using Robot Framework AutoIt Library.
I can handle the windows that comes subsequent after clicking the Save or Save As option.[image: The image is attached here for reference]

Comment: AFAIK, the pop-up screen does not have useful window properties AND it is not possible to _tab_ your way through the options. Only solution I can think of using AutoIT is to use [MouseClick](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/MouseClick.htm) on the coordinates of the button you want to click on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of file are you downloading?  Depending on the file type you should be able to set a default behaviour in IE11.

Personally I think AutoIT solutions with this are overkill, I'd recommend looking at the following blog post for alternative ideas if possible:

https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2010/07/file-downloads-with-selenium-mission-impossible/

However, if this is a scenario you simply MUST automate as you're doing then my first line should help you.

Comment: I tried few options found online to change default download behavior of IE11 but those were not successful. Is there any resource you recommend?

Comment: I can certainly use python urlib2 or requests module instead of wget to download the file. But I have had a situation in past when the file could be downloaded in Chrome but not in IE. So if I use wget, then i will skip testing the browser specific scenario. That may lead to a false positive.

Comment: but do you want to test the download functionality in each browser?  This is browser implementation and not something you can actually do or change?